# Linking a List Item to a Document Library in a subsite

Tags: list, document, library, item

I am trying to link a list item to a report saved in a document library in a sub site.

Is this possible or should i move the document library to the hub page?
(the list is in the hub page)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **lookup column** as a **Site column** from the list you want to refer in your site collection.

Then you will be able to **add the newly created lookup column in your document library** at subsite level.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632).
2. [Adding an existing site column to document library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2) - Check the section "Add an existing site column to a SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2019 list or library"

**Other useful References**:

1. [How to Create a Cross-Site Lookup Site Column in SharePoint?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/how-to-create-cross-site-lookup-site-column-in-sharepoint.html)